# What is use of feature.xml in moss2007?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, file

What are the exact use of feature.xml, onet.xml, webtemp.xml ?
please describe....

Comment: 24 questions and 0 acceptance.

Comment: It's almost impossible to believe these questions are even real at this point.

Comment: which point u are talking about. I want to know what those exact , so i asked.... right . i think Forum is design for that purpose right chris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[feature.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475601.aspx)

[Functions of Onet.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474369.aspx)

[webtemp.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms447717.aspx)

I just googled that for you.

Comment: Thnks i will follow  all your suggessions

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read the book [Inside Microsoft® Windows® SharePoint® Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/9692.aspx)

Comment: +1. This book is a great look at the fundamentals of sharepoint from a dev perspective.  Well worth buying.